# How to correctly deserialize RabbitMQ message containing top level array from JSON

Tags: json, go, rabbitmq

I try to do it this way:

```
        case message := <-Rmq.Messages:
            go func() {
                log.Printf("Process message: %s", message.MessageId)

                rmqMessages := make([]RmqMessage, 100)
                err := json.Unmarshal(message.Body, &rmqMessages)
                if err != nil {
                    log.Fatalf("Error decoding %s: %v", message.Body, err)
                }

                var (
                    pushResult FcmResponse
                    rmqMessage RmqMessage
                )
                for _, rmqMessage = range rmqMessages {
```

It works some iterations, than failed with `Error decoding : unexpected end of JSON input` and `message.Body == nil`. But everything works fine, if JSON is not a list of objects (`[{...}, {...}, ...]` but just a single object `{...}`

I've tried

```
    RmqMessages struct {
        Messages []RmqMessage
    }
    rmqMessages := RmqMessages{}
    err := json.Unmarshal(message.Body, &rmqMessages.Messages)
```

with same result

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: If it works "sometimes" but not other times, the problem isn't with the decoding. If `message.Body` is `nil`, maybe `Rmq.Messages` is closed and you receive the zero value from it? Use the special `message, ok := <- Rmq.Messages` form to tell if the channel is closed or not. If `ok` is `false`, the channel was closed.

Answer (score 1):

The error was in `ack`ing the message in the loop iterating over deserialized array